# Open source server application for exception handling?

Tags: .net, exception

Is there some open source alternative to [Hoptoad](http://www.hoptoadapp.com/) and [Exceptioneer](http://exceptioneer.com/)? We would like to host the exception "aggregation" application at our site.

We receive tens of .NET exceptions from users in the field each day. Thus we need a way to organize them, find duplicates and prioritize fixing the exceptions that happen most often. Hoptoad is nice and easy to use, but based on our initial tests it didn't perform too well in matching similar exceptions and it doesn't seem to support storing/displaying all the information we need.

I am looking for a tool that could be extended for our needs and deployed on our servers. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

It doesn't aggregate them but it does have a SQL Server provider that you could access and create the kinds of reports you need.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I already knew about ELMAH, but I am specifically looking for a web frontend. I have already written a tool that imports the reported exceptions into a database that I can do queries on.

Comment: @Filip: ELMAH does have a simple web front-end and RSS

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer, I know, but it doesn't have aggregation of exceptions of the same type (ie. with the same stack trace).